# How to mathematically state y - 1 unless y - 1 < 0 then y is 0

Tags: terminology

I have a formula and I don't know how to write it in mathematical form (I'm a programmer.)

The formula needs the variable y to be y - 1 unless y <= 0, in which case y should just be 0.

Programmatically, it would look like this:

```
if (y > 0) then
  y = y - 1
else
  y = 0
```

How does one write this using proper mathematical terminology?

Comment: $$\max\{y-1,0\}\quad\text{or}\quad\tfrac12(y-1+|y-1|)\quad\text{or}\ldots$$

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Comment: Technically, even if you did not have a different assignment for the case where $y \leq 0$, the mathematical form of `y=y-1` would still not be $y=y-1$. Instead you might have $y' = y-1$, $y_{n+1} = y_n - 1$, or some even more complicated structure. So it becomes a rather open-ended question to ask, "How does one write this using proper mathematical terminology?"

Comment: @jpreed00 You are welcome.

Comment: @Did : your proposed solution gives 0 for y=1/2 instead of  -1/2

Comment: @Tryss Should `y` be an integer? Anyway, the OP got the idea and can adapt it to their specific situation, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "assignment" in mathematics (it's a bit different from equivalence, e.g. $y=y-1$ is a *statement*, rather than an operation), unless you're speaking of a function. In such a case it would look something like (rewriting what you've said explicitly):

$$
f(y) = \begin{cases}
y-1, &\text{if } y>0\\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: It might also make more sense writing this as a recursion, since this might be inside of a loop of some sort: $$y_{n+1} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} y_n - 1 & y_n > 0\\ 0 & y_n \le 0 \end{array}\right.$$